# Filled rect disappear after mouse releasing

Tags: class, for-loop, image-processing, arraylist, processing

I’m new to processing. I am looking to write a program in which I select an area of an image ( like “rect selection” in Photoshop for example…), this area has a red stroke and is slightly opaque, once the area is selected, the rectangle fills with the average color of the pixels of the same area and the red stroke turns off. The idea is to be able to repeat this action several times on the same image. When I released the mouse, the fill is erased because of `background(buff);` in `void draw();`. I would like the rectangle filled with the new color to be saved. I think I need to use an array, class, but I don’t understand how these work. If someone is able to help me, it would be a great help. Thank you.

```java
PImage buff1;
int x1,y1,x2,y2,h1,h2;

void setup()
{
    size(1000, 721);
    buff1 = loadImage("buff1.jpg2);
    background(buff1);
}

color extractColorFromImage(final PImage buff1) {
    buff1.loadPixels();
    color r = 1, g = 1, b = 1;

    for (final color c : buff1.pixels) {
        r += c >> 020 & 255;
        g += c >> 010 & 255;
        b += c & 255;
    }
    r /= buff1.pixels.length;
    g /= buff1.pixels.length;
    b /= buff1.pixels.length;
    return color(r, g, b);
}

void draw()
{
    background(buff1);
    rectMode(CORNERS);
    stroke(255,0,0);
    strokeWeight(2);
    strokeJoin(ROUND);
    rect(x1,y1,x2,y2,2);
    fill(255,0,0,50);
    noStroke();
    cursor(ARROW);
}

void mousePressed()
{
    x1 = mouseX;
    y1 = mouseY;
}

void mouseDragged()
{
    x2 = mouseX;
    y2 = mouseY;
}

void mouseReleased()
{
    int H1 = abs(1+x2-x1);
    int H2 = abs(1+y2-y1);

    for (int i=0; i<width; i+=H1)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<height; j+=H2)
        {
            PImage newImg = buff1.get(x1, y1, H1, H2);
            fill(extractColorFromImage(newImg), 40);
            noStroke();
            cursor(ARROW);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the pixel data for an image have been loaded by [`loadPixels()`](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_loadPixels_.html), the loaded pixels can be accessed and changed by [`pixels[]`](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_pixels.html).
[`updatePixels()`](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_pixels.html) updates the image with the data in its p`ixels[]` array:

```java
void mouseReleased()
{
    int x_1 = min(x1,x2);
    int y_1 = min(y1,y2);
    int x_2 = max(x1,x2);
    int y_2 = max(y1,y2);

    PImage newImg = buff1.get(x_1, y_1, x_2-x1+1, y_2-y1+1);
    color new_color = extractColorFromImage(newImg);

    buff1.loadPixels();
    for (int i = x_1; i <= x_2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = y_1; j <= y_2; j++)
        {
             buff1.pixels[j*buff1.width+i] = new_color;
        }
    }
    buff1.updatePixels();
}
```

---

When the mouse button is pressed, then I recommend to set (`x2`, `y2`), too:

```java
void mousePressed()
{
    x1 = mouseX;
    y1 = mouseY;
    x2 = x1;
    y2 = y1;
}
```

---

[image]

---

Optionally the original color can be mixed with the new color by [`lerpColor()`](https://processing.org/reference/lerpColor_.html):

```py
PImage newImg = buff1.get(x_1, y_1, x_2-x1+1, y_2-y1+1);
color new_color = extractColorFromImage(newImg);

buff1.loadPixels();
for (int i = x_1; i <= x_2; i++)
{
    for (int j = y_1; j <= y_2; j++)
    {
         color orig_color = buff1.pixels[j*buff1.width+i];
         buff1.pixels[j*buff1.width+i] = lerpColor(orig_color, new_color, 0.5); 
    }
}
buff1.updatePixels();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but now where can I adjust the opacity of this new color. I do not see where to add the alpha channel in this code.

Comment: @Antang [`color()`](https://processing.org/reference/color_.html) can take a 4th parameter `color(r, g, b, 128)`. But note, colors can be mixed by [`lerpColor()`](https://processing.org/reference/lerpColor_.html). e.g. `color orig_color = buff1.pixels[j*buff1.width+i];` `buff1.pixels[j*buff1.width+i] = lerpColor(orig_color, new_color, 0.5);`. I've added that option to the answer, right now